# Python Bottle installation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I downloaded "bottle.py" and put it in my project directory. I created a simple "helloworld.py" . Helloworld.py is

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')

def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I run this file, errors pop up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kattula/PycharmProjects/Sample Codes/helloworld.py", line 6, in <module>
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\kattula\PycharmProjects\Sample Codes\bottle.py", line 3112, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "C:\Users\kattula\PycharmProjects\Sample Codes\bottle.py", line 2766, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, app, server_cls, handler_cls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 144, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 48, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the bug. Help !. Thanks in advance. `

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Are you local admin on that machine? This looks to me like a security issue because you're trying to start a server on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

The error code reported (10013) is [Permission Denied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so I'm guessin gyou are running under Windows with UAC. Check out this post [Admin privileges for script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874476/admin-privileges-for-script)